# How to add credentials authorization when using yarp reverse proxy

Tags: c#, .net, ms-yarp

I've successfully set up YARP as a reverse proxy, and it works well for routes that don't require authorization. However, I'm facing challenges when trying to include credentials for accessing destination APIs or sites. Can anyone guide me on how to manage this aspect with YARP?

This is what I tried before. But, it seems the credentials(`HTTP_Authorization`) is not working. I have `userName` and `password`, but don't know where to put it. And maybe it's not best to put it the `userName` and `password` on config files right?

```
  "ReverseProxy": {
    "Routes": {
      "route1": {
        "ClusterId": "cluster1",
        "Order": 1,
        "Match": {
          "Path": "/somePath/{**path1}"
        },
        "Transforms": [
          {
            "PathPattern": "/somePattern/{**path1}"
          }, 
          {
            "RequestHeader": "HTTP_Authorization",
            "Set": "Basic someAuthorizationHashKey"
          }
        ]
      },
    },
    "Clusters": {
      "cluster1": {
        "Destinations": {
          "destination1": {
            "Address": "https://someSitewithCredentials"
          }
        }
      },
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrong request header. In IIS, the header is `HTTP_Authorization`. I thought it's same with yarp. But for yarp reverse proxy, it works with `Authorization`.

And for `username` and `password`, it reflects on `someAuthorizationHashKey`.

So, it's closed case